# I am trying to write a bash script that displays 10 different random numbers, so far some of the numbers that I have are duplicated

Tags: bash, shell

I think there is something wrong with the condition and the array.
this is my script
thank you for your time I appreciate.

```
#!/bin/bash

loop=10
range=20
count=1
declare -a prev
numb=$[1+RANDOM% $range]
prev+=($numb)

echo ===========================
echo $loop DIFFERENT RANDOM NUMBERS
echo ===========================

echo $numb

until [ "$count" -ge "$loop" ]
do
    numb=$[1+RANDOM% $range]

    if [[ ${prev[@]} -ne $numb ]] ; then
        echo $numb
        prev+=$numb
        ((count++))
    fi
done
```

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) points out that arrays will simply [concatenate](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2199) in `[[...]]`, and that you should use a loop instead

Comment: That's because 10 random numbers drawn from the same distribution *should* produce duplicates. Requiring that a given number cannot match a previously generated number means you need to use a different distribution to generate that number.

Comment: Run your code with shell debug-trace set, add `set -vx` at the top of your script. Your `[[ ${prev[@]} -ne $numb ]]` isn't working the way you think it is. Good luck.

Comment: This might hellp: `seq 10 | shuf`

Comment: `prev+=$numb` doesn't add a new array element, it does a string append to the first element (i.e. if `prev[0]=15` and you execute `prev+=7`, you wind up with `prev[0]=157`). You want `prev+=($numb)`. Except you probably don't, because bash doesn't have a good way to test whether a value occurs in an array, so an array isn't the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Cyrus, requirements here seem to indicate `seq 20 | shuf | head -n 10`

Comment: Thank you all for the constructive explanation, I now understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code attempt to locate previously selected numbers by using the conditions `[[ ${prev[@]} -ne $numb ]]`. However, bash does not have "in" (or "not in") operators that work on an array and a value.

Consider instead using bash associative arrays. Each used elements is marked by entering a value into the position associated with the selected number

```
#! /bin/bash

loop=10
range=20
  # Associative array prev[N]=1, if N was already printed
declare -A prev

echo ===========================
echo $loop DIFFERENT RANDOM NUMBERS
echo ===========================


for ((count=1 ; count <= loop ; count++)) ; do
    numb=$[1+RANDOM% $range]
    while [ "${prev[$numb]}" ] ; do
        numb=$[1+RANDOM% $range]
    done ;
    echo $numb
    prev[$numb]=1
done
```

Code using traditional for loop `for (( ; ; ))` to force loop to run specific number of times.

Comment: thank you, I now see the difference in array types. and simple loop. It even looks more readable. cheers

Answer (score 1):

A quick version using an array -

```
$: loop=10 min=20 range=20 all=( $( seq $min $((min+range)) ) )
$: while (( loop-- ))
   do ndx=$((RANDOM%range))
      if (( all[ndx] ))
      then echo "${all[ndx]}"
           unset "all[ndx]"
      else let loop++
      fi
   done
33
38
27
23
39
32
22
20
36
35
```

Unsetting each element as used prevents dups.
I'm pretty sure there's a better way... still thinking.

Comment: "Accept the solution" means to click the checkmark that marks it as an accepted solution.  c.f. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).